# Boolean comparison of array of strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've got an array in Ruby that essentially represents a square boolean matrix. Dots represent zeroes, while any other character represents ones. Example:

```
irb(main):044:0> g
=> [".b", "m."] # This grid has two '1' values and two '0' values.
```

I'd like to perform a specified logical operation (say, OR) on this array with another similar array to get a third result. For example, if `h` is `["q.", "r."]`, then something akin to `g.perform_or(h)` should yield a new array `["qb", "r."]`. (The choice of `r` to represent the result of `'m' || 'r'` is arbitrary and not relevant; any other non-'.' character can be there.)

How might I do this?

---

Edit: I made an error in my example. Apologies!

Comment: If '.' == 0 and /[^.]/ == 1, your example of an or function is wrong.

Comment: So, outside of the actual answer I'm curious about what you're doing with this? Sounds interesting!

Comment: If you change the problem statement, you waste the time of all those who tried to answer your question before you change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For OR:

```
g.zip(h).map {|gx,hx| (0...gx.size).map {|i| [gx[i..i],hx[i..i]].any? {|cell| cell != "."} ? "x" : "."}.join}
```

For AND just change the "any?" to "all?".

Comment: I was trying to understand this and I'm not getting the same result as specified above. I'm getting ['xx', 'x.']. Even if you had transposed . and x it should look like ['xx', '.x']. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Me too. It should actually look like `['..', 'x.']`

Comment: glenn deserves a double bump then for finding the right answer and the right question :P

Answer (score 0):

Man, this one has been gathering dust on my disk for a *loong* time:

```
class String
  def to_bool; return chars.map {|c| if c == '.' then false else c end } end
  def from_bool; return self end
end

class TrueClass;  def from_bool; return 't' end end
class FalseClass; def from_bool; return '.' end end

class Array
  def to_bool;   map(&:to_bool) end
  def from_bool; map {|row| row.map(&:from_bool).join} end

  def |(other)
    to_bool.zip(other.to_bool).inject([]) {|row, (l, r)|
      row << l.zip(r).inject([]) {|col, (l, r)|
        col << (l || r).from_bool
      }
    }
  end

  def &(other)
    to_bool.zip(other.to_bool).inject([]) {|row, (l, r)|
      row << l.zip(r).inject([]) {|col, (l, r)|
        col << (l && r).from_bool
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Here's a (rather incomplete) testsuite:

```
require 'test/unit'
class TestLogicMatrix < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_to_bool
    assert_equal [['a', false], [false, 'z']], ['a.', '.z'].to_bool
  end
  def test_from_bool
    assert_equal ['a.', 'tz'], [['a', false], [true, 'z']].from_bool
  end
  def test_that_OR_works
    assert_equal ['qb', 'm.'], (['.b', 'm.'] | ['q.', 'r.']).from_bool
  end
  def test_that_AND_works
    assert_equal ['..', 'r.'], (['.b', 'm.'] & ['q.', 'r.']).from_bool
  end
end
```